# How do I create a working menu screen for this p5 Javascript sketch?

Tags: javascript, html, processing, p5.js

I have created several different versions of Pong, and stored them as different functions. I have then tried to access these functions using buttons on the screen, with each button press being mapped to its corresponding function. However, when I click one of the buttons none of the functions are loaded and the user can only see the menu screen; basically nothing happens.

Comment: Add the pertinent code here. Shouldn't have to go to an external site.

Comment: its just easier this way

Comment: Just a tip, you aren't going to get nearly as many replies as you would. If you embedded here.

Comment: Easier for you, not for those you are asking to help you for free ;)

Comment: I disagree, I'd much rather a p5 program be plonked into the p5 editor then I don't need to go through the laborious task of settings up the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close, you have the right idea. What I've done is I've setup how I would do this using just your `Epilepsymode` code (mainly because I was curious to see what it looked like) :D

I have added a flag so you can know which game is currently active, you'll have to do something like this for all the games and disable their corresponding flags when they're not active.

```
let isEpilepsyMode = false;
let epilepsyMode;  // represents the epilepseMode object
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400,400)
  background(0)
  menu();
}

function draw() {
  if (isEpilepsyMode) {
    epilepsyMode.draw();
  }
}
```

I've added a new handler for when you click the button:

```
  button5.mousePressed(beginEpilepsyMode);
```

Handler:

```
function beginEpilepsyMode() {
    isEpilepsyMode = true;
    epilepsyMode = new Epilepsymode();
    epilepsyMode.setup();
}
```

Setup and Draw are methods of the `Epilepsymode` object, so in order to write `epilepsyMode.setup()`:

```
function Epilepsymode() {
    clear();
    hideButtons();
    let Lscore = 0;
    let Rscore = 0;
    let r2 = 0;
    let b2 = 255;
    let button;
    balls = []

    this.setup = function() {
        createCanvas(800, 400);
        menu();
        ball = new Ball();
        left = new Paddle(true);
        right = new Paddle(false);

        for (let i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
            balls[i] = new Ball()
        }
    }

    this.draw = function() {
        background(0);
        r2 = map(right.y, 0, 400, 255, 0)
        b2 -= map(left.y, 400, 800, 0, 255)
        background(r2, 0, b2)

        for (let i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
            balls[i].update();
            balls[i].edges();
            balls[i].show();
            balls[i].checkPaddleRight(right)
            balls[i].checkPaddleLeft(left)
        }
        ball.checkPaddleRight(right);
        ball.checkPaddleLeft(left);

        left.show();
        right.show();
        left.update();
        right.update();

        ball.update();
        ball.edges();
        ball.show();

        fill(255);
        textSize(32);
        text(Lscore, 32, 40);
        text(Rscore, width - 64, 40);

    }
```

So if you go to [this sketch](https://editor.p5js.org/codeheir/sketches/S1pcyVfG4) you'll see that the epilepsy button produces the epilepsy version of your game.

Comment: Good solution! I'd personally use a number representing the game rather than flags but the result is the same.

Comment: Yeah I'm sure there's a tonne of clever ways of doing it, thank you

Comment: Thanks a lot for help! I really appreciate it. I adapted your solution to all of my code, but I encountered a few problems such as the inability to move the paddles or click the mouse and cause an output as a result of this, in any of the game modes and I'm not too sure why this is. Lscore and Rscore don't work in NormalMultiplayer either. This is a link to the updated sketch: https://editor.p5js.org/lahirurajapaksa/sketches/HklVcnVfMN

Comment: would really appreciate any additional help if you have the time!

Comment: Sure, so your keyPressed function should not be in the scope of your object. So plonk it below the main draw() function but not within your object. Ideally you'd only have one keyPressed function, not one for each game.